# How to add balance to the user's account of a website directly, where payment gets done in the coinbase?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, coinbase-api

We are building a website where the payment is done by coinbase. Here the logged in users of the website adds credit to their account through payment from coinbase using the btc address. We added the coinbase API with our website, but we are struggling with the step where the user's account is automatically detected and credit is added to their account while the payment phase is completed in coinbase.

**Can anyone describe the process or give us useful documentation link of coinbase API by which we can solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you checked for their API Docs. Let me know how is it working for you.
https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/sign-in-with-coinbase/docs/send-and-receive-btc